# ElasticSearch Heap size not reflecting after setting environment variable

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm

I have set ES_HEAP_SIZE environment variable and after restarting my elasticsearch when i check ps -aux | grep elasticsearch it shows -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m . But when i do echo $ES_HEAP_SIZE it shows me correct value.

```
Sequence of commands

vim /etc/environments

Add export ES_HEAP_SIZE=7g

Save And Exit

source /etc/environments

Then

/bin/elasticsearch restart
```

I checked in /bin/elasticsearch.in.sh it has a code block

```
if [ "x$ES_MIN_MEM" = "x" ]; then
    ES_MIN_MEM=256m
fi
if [ "x$ES_MAX_MEM" = "x" ]; then
    ES_MAX_MEM=1g
fi
if [ "x$ES_HEAP_SIZE" != "x" ]; then
    ES_MIN_MEM=$ES_HEAP_SIZE
    ES_MAX_MEM=$ES_HEAP_SIZE
fi
```

It sets minimum to 256m and maximum to 1g but in process list it shows 4G min and 4G maximum and heap size is 7G. Please suggest me how to reflect minimum and maximum equal to heap size. Also in mentioned code what it is referring to x means what is the value of x is the comparing with and I have not set ES_MIN_MEM and ES_MAX_MEM environment variables.

Comment: Where did you set `ES_HEAP_SIZE`? Just in your shell or in another configuration file (such as `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch`)?

Comment: I set /etc/environment with export ES_HEAP_SIZE=7g then source /etc/environment and I am able to see echo $ES_HEAP_SIZE

Comment: You can but the ES process probably can't. Do you have the file `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch` (RHEL) or `/etc/default/elasticsearch` (Ubuntu)? What does it say?

Comment: No i do not have /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch

Comment: How did you install ES? Using a ZIP file?

Comment: Through source yes using a zip file

Comment: Are you sourcing your script `/etc/environment` in the same shell as the one you start ES in? Can you show your `/etc/environment` file?

Comment: My /etc/environment file only contains one line export ES_HEAP_SIZE=7g and post saving file I did source /etc/environment

Comment: How much physical RAM do you have by the way?

Comment: I have 16G RAM available and set 7G for heap size

Comment: Can you update your question with the series of commands your launch in your shell and the output of each?

Comment: Added sequence of commands

Comment: Are you sure you only have one single ES process running and you're looking at the right one? Also what OS are you on and what ES version are you using?

Comment: Hey apologize for late response. When I do ps -aux | grep elasticsearch it shows two process one for elastic search and one for JVM with -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m